# Bubble sort algorithm - do i have an error?

Tags: python, algorithm, bubble-sort

I was following an online website tutorial on bubble sort and decided to do it myself before looking at the answer.

I get this:

```
 def bubbleSort(theList):
     i=0
     while i < len(theList)-1:
         if theList[i+1] < theList[i]:
             theList[i],theList[i+1] = theList[i+1],theList[i]
         i=i+1

     return theList

 myList = [13,5,6,2,10,11]
 print(bubbleSort(myList))
```

but in the answer they have:

```
 def bubbleSort(alist):
     for passnum in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1):
         for i in range(passnum):
             if alist[i]>alist[i+1]:
                 temp = alist[i]
                 alist[i] = alist[i+1]
                 alist[i+1] = temp

 alist = [54,26,93,17,77,31,44,55,20]
 bubbleSort(alist)
 print(alist)
```

the problem i have is that my answer works but i dont understand why there is an extra line in the example answer:

```
  for passnum in range(len(alist)-1,0,-1):
```

whats the point of this? also in other examples i also see 2 for loops being used. is there an error with my code? it seems to work

Comment: Your answer does **not** work! You only do one pass, so only 13 bubbles to the end.

Comment: Your code outputs [5, 6, 2, 10, 11, 13] I have some concerns about the 2. Yes, you need two loops to perform bubble sort.

Comment: An extremely small amount of testing shows that your code fails. It failed on the very first example I ran it on. It isn't clear why you say that it "seems to work".

Comment: Also by definition bubble sort requires two loops....

Comment: Read about how a bubble sort works and you'll see why a single loop cannot work.  You'll look at each element (first loop) and compare it against all other elements (so a second loop is needed).  There are some good animated visual examples out there that can show how this is working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You make *just one pass* of the bubble sort. You code is correct, but it only brings *the one, largest element* to the end of the list. You should repeat the code `n` times, with the range reducing by one each time.

You should note that your code has complexity O(n), which bubblesort has O(n^2).

Comment: Out of curiosity why use $ to express big O?

Comment: @Error-SyntacticalRemorse: bad formatting. most related sites render equation in $$ in latex format, but for some reason stackoveflow doesn't

Comment: @blue_note The idea has been discussed on meta: https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/30559/357835